# Add comment to line in multiline %w in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, comments

I have a multiline string array via percent string like this:

```
array = %w(test
           foo
           bar)
```

I want to add a comment message to the `foo` entry, something like

```
array = %w(test
           # TODO: Remove this line after fix #1
           foo
           bar)
```

Is there any way to do it without converting it to basic array like this?

```
array = ['test',
         # TODO: Remove this line after fix #1
         'foo',
         'bar']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is no way to make that work, because `%w()` evaluates every space delimited element inside it to string.

There's no way from inside the string to make Ruby evaluate that string.

Answer (score 5):

The only and tricky way:

```
array = %W(test
           #@foo
           bar).reject(&:empty?)
```

Note capital `W` and `reject`

Comment: I don't think it qualifies as a good answer since it provides a workaround, and not a solution (which most likely does not exist).

Comment: I think it is fair to show readers that this workaround exists, so I suggest people to upvote instead of downvoting this response.